# How to swap two objects without copy assignment operator?

Tags: c++, swap, copy-assignment

I have a class A where, the copy assignment operator is deleted. How should I swap two instances of A ?

I tried using `std::swap` but that did not work.

```
class A {
private:
    int a;
public:
    A& operator=(const A& other) = delete;
    A(int _a = 0):a(_a){}
    void showA() { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A obj1(10);
    A obj2(20);
    obj1.showA();
    obj2.showA();
    //A temp;
    //temp = obj1;
    //obj1 = obj2;
    //obj2 = temp;
    obj1.showA();
    obj2.showA();
}
```

I expect `obj1` and `obj2` to be swapped. Initially `obj1.a` is `10` and `obj2.a` is `20`, I expect `obj1.a` to be `20` and `obj2.a`to be `10` when done.

Comment: You can overload `swap`.

Comment: If there's no public interface for modifying `a` then you can't swap two objects without modifying the class itself.

Comment: `std::swap` doesn't require copy assignment operator, but it requires move constructor and move assignment operator. Since copy assignment is declared (as deleted), move constructors are no longer implicitly defined and should be declared explicitly (e.g. with `default` keyword).

Comment: @molbdnilo That would require modifying the class, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @rranjik: The crux of the problem is that the `A` class is immutable. So no, there's no way to swap values. You have to swap the entire instance, which is tricky to do on the stack. See `std::optional`.

Comment: @MooingDuck,@Kevin Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Yksisarvinen indicated you need to have move constructor and move assignment defined in order to get `std::move` to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> 

class A {
private:
    int a;
public:
    A(int a_) : a(a_) {}
    A(const A& other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&& other) { 
        a = other.a;
    }
    A& operator=(A&& other) { 
        a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }
    void showA() { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A obj1(10);
    A obj2(20);
    obj1.showA();
    obj2.showA();

    std::swap(obj1, obj2);
    std::cout << "swapped:" << std::endl;
    obj1.showA();
    obj2.showA();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great one !  To avoid some unnecessary typing and later maintenance, I'd suggest to define the move constructor and move assignment as default (see https://ideone.com/gfKvBO)